# use javascript methos from iframe into my page(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have loaded an iframe in my page. The purpose of doing this is to use Javascript methods from that link which is being loaded in iframe. Is this possible? If so, how?

I ahve tried to directly call the methods in my Javascript, but I think it will work only if the iframe is loaded before my javascript is being executed.

Waiting for your suggestions.

```
  myobj._myFirstJs.prototype.init = function () {

  $("#load").click( function (){
  myobj. = new myobj._myclass(myobj,homeComingUrl);
  myobj.myclass.getEmployee();
  console.log("called");   
  }); 
 });
}
```

I have tryied this code. I am calling these lines when a button (id=load)is been clicked.
I don't understand why its norking, afterall its being called after the whole page is being loaded.

Comment: Its very clear that i want to call js method in my js file which is loaded through iframe, thats it, y u need code for that @Vaibs_Cool

Comment: I have added a code @Vaibs_Cool, what i tried. Know can explain y this is not working, couse logically after all js files being loaded the methods can be called, but y not in this case.

Comment: have you tried my code in your click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your iFrame's id is "yourIFrame" and the function you want to call is yourFunction():

```
document.getElementById('yourIFrame').contentWindow.yourFunction();
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run Javascript on an iframed page is if there is no violation of cross-origin policies. Assuming that is okay, you can access the embedded page with:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
console.log(iframeDoc);
```